# creating dynamic textbox in front of each row retrieve from db in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

I am retrieving values from database and wanted to add textbox dynamically in front of each row.After that i want to fetch the values from each textbox and save in the database table on clicking button.

```
<%
ResultSet rs;
try
{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost.com:1521/xe","name","password");    
String sql="select * from marks where dept_id='"+deptId+"' and c_id='"+cId+"'   ";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
%>
<tr><td><h3>Student ID </h3></td>
<td><h3>Enter Marks </h3></td></tr>

<% 
int i=1;

while(rs.next())
{   int row=rs.getRow();
    String s_id = rs.getString("s_id");
%>
<tr><td>
<ul>
    <li><%=s_id %></li>
    </ul></td>
    <td><input type="text"  name ="id" id="id"/></td> 


<% 
out.println(i);
String mark=request.getParameter("id");


%>

<%

String strProcedure="{call insertmarks(?,?,?,?)}";

CallableStatement cs=conn.prepareCall(strProcedure);

cs.setString(1,deptId); 
cs.setString(2,cId); 
cs.setString(3,s_id); 
cs.setString(4,mark); 
cs.execute();


i++;
}

%>
<td><input type="submit" value="update" /> </td>
        </tr>
<%



}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
%>
```

I m retrieving deptId and cId through session.getAttribute().Basically i m creating student management system application and want faculty to update marks of all the students that belong to his department and course and then save the marks column of database table.

Comment: okay , where is your code ,post that .

Comment: Side note: never EVER use string concatenation to create SQL commands from user input, not even in a school project. This makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

Comment: ok thanks i will keep that in mind.

Comment: Can you please provide solution for this

Comment: Well, there is no straightforward solution. You should split your code according to the [Model-View-Controller](https://www.baeldung.com/mvc-servlet-jsp) pattern. Put all the business logic (JDBC) into a servlets, and use JSP only to display the results.

Comment: One important thing is to name each of the text fields differently, I would use something like `<input type="text" name="mark<%=s_id %>" id="id"/>`. If you use the same name (`id`) for them, then `request.getParameter("id")` will give you only the value of the first one. You would have to use `request.getParameterValues("id")` to get all the values, but then you don't know which value belongs to which id.